# "Due to address" vs. "Due to addressing"

Tags: grammaticality, expression-choice

Which is correct?

> 1. Due to address the convention in July, Brown planned to address the issue of low-income housing in his speech.
> 2. Due to addressing the convention in July, Brown planned to address the issue of low-income housing in his speech.

*(Sentence 1 from Barron's Verbal Workbook)*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about as lazy as posting test questions go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is correct, although I would personally choose a synonym for the second use of *address*.

What's the difference?

1. Brown is going to address (speak in front of) the convention in July. He plans to address (speak about) the issue of low-income housing in his speech.
2. Brown had addressed (spoken in front of) the convention in July. As a result, he plans to address (speak about) the issue of low-income housing in his speech.

The second sentence indicates a nonsensical causality.

Comment: Are you disallowing the reading/s <<2 Because he would be addressing the convention in July, Brown planned to mention the issue of low-income housing in his speech.>>?

Comment: Agreed. There are at least two legit readings of version 2. As well as Edwin's there is the case where the second is talking about some other address. "Because he would be addressing the convention in July, Brown planned to address the issue of low-income housing [at the September symposium]".

Comment: The preposed clause beginning _Due to_ is short for _He was due to_; so would you say _He was due to address the convention,_ or _He was due to addressing the convention_? And who addresses the convention, in either case?

Comment: Good suggestions. I'll update the answer to account for them.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing *addressing* as anything other than a gerund in the preposed clause of the second sentence. As a result, Edwin's interpretation seems incorrect to me. To arrive at Edwin's interpretation, the preposed clause must read, "Due to *be* addressing the convention in July".

Answer (score -1):

Because of "due to" meaning "owing to" or "because of", I had trouble understanding the meaning of that sentence in  barrows book too, but i found a meaning that makes perfect sense: "Due (expected) to address the convention in July, Brown planned to address the issue of low-income housing in his speech." It's not the compound two-word preposition "due to" but the adjective "due", and it means "expected."